# NET.Core и kestrel: не получается захостить статические файлы директивой app.UseStaticFiles()

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, kestrel

Только начал пробовать использование kestrel в net core приложениях.

Пробую все на net core 5.0 на виндовс.

Написал вроде бы минимально возможную конфигурацию.

Запускаю, кладу файл index.html рядом с exe-шником, и думаю, что если я зайду по адресу `http://localhost:5000/index.html` - то увижу статическую страницу.

Но нет, вызывается дефолтный обработчик.

Я в него специально вставил `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` чтобы видеть, из какой директории всё запускается.

Нет ни у кого идей, где у меня ошибка? Любые советы по конфигурации будут приняты с благодарностью :-)

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;

    namespace ServerApp {
        public class Program {
            public static void Main(string[] args) {

                var host = new WebHostBuilder().UseKestrel(GetKso()).UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).UseStartup<Startup>().Build();
                host.Run();

            }

            static Action<KestrelServerOptions> GetKso() {
                Action<KestrelServerOptions> ret = options =>
                {
                    options.Limits.MaxConcurrentConnections = 100;
                    options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5000);
                };
                return ret;
            }


        }

        public class Startup {
            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
            }

            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
                if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                }

                app.UseStaticFiles();

                app.Run(async (context) =>
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync($"current dir: {Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}");
                });
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: [Static files in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0). Статические файлы должны быть расположены в Web root по умолчанию.

Comment: А если каталог для теста явно задать? Абсолютный путь. ([я долго крутил колесо мыши, но ничего не понял](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1))

Comment: Спасибо большое. Как я понимаю, web root по умолчанию - это рабочая директория самого приложения. Я проверил -  env.ContentRootPath указывает именно туда. Туда же, куда и Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(). И во всех примерах все отталкивается от этой директории, типа Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "MyStaticFiles")). Я смотрел в пример  https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/2.5.php - но там всё якобы работает сразу. Попробовал создать папку wwwroot - не помогло

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Помогло явное задание папки: var host = new WebHostBuilder().UseKestrel(GetKso()).UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).UseStartup<Startup>().UseWebRoot("static").Build(); Будете оформлять как ответ?

Comment: Вы к кому сейчас обратились?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Ответы в ответы?

Comment: @aepot  > Вы к кому сейчас обратились? - Мне фактически помог Ваш совет. Если Вам удобно - напишите его как ответ?

Comment: @S.H. будет прикольнее, если вы напишите ответ, потому что я тупо дал ссылку на док, а ответ вы сами нашли. А так я без понятия, что такое Kestrel и с чем его едят xD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Как приручить пустельгу**

Чтобы не загромождать текст кодом, я положил его в [гитхаб](https://github.com/junecat/KestrelExample).

asp.net - технология, которую Microsoft приготовила на замену более старой технологии Microsoft ASP. В то же время asp.net была неразрывно связана с Windows и IIS (ну, или IIS Express - при локальной разработке и отладке).

IIS - прекрасный сервер, но иногда хочется чего то более компактного.
Ведь для минимального веб-сервера нужно не так уж много кода.

И с появлением NET Core появилась простая возможность использовать кроссплатформенный web-сервер, называемый kestrel (полное название - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel).

Кроме кросплатформенности, плюсом kestrel является возможность встроить его в своё приложение. Давайте попробуем решить минимальную задачу: написать консольное приложение, ктоорое имеет встроенный веб-сервер, который умеет отображать статические страницы и отвечать на REST - запросы.

**Шаг 1.**
Напишем простое консольное NET Core приложение. Обычный шаблон консольного приложения просто печатает "Hello world!" в консоли. Теперь добавим код, котрый запускает веб-сервер. Пропустив несколько скучных шагов, я приведу сразу пример кода:

Несколько пояснений.

Для того, чтобы этот код скомпилировался, нужно сделать доступным простанства имён, находящиеся в пакете Microsoft.AspNetCore. Для этого нужно в файл проекта *.csproj добавить секцию

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

В результате при любом обращении к любому адресу
http://localhost:5000/<что угодно>
мы получаем страницу с надписью "Hello, world".

**Шаг 2.**
Добавляем статические страницы.
Для этого понадобится сделать три дополнения:

а) Добавить в строку конфигурирования WebHost директиву UseWebRoot("static"):
строка
var host = new WebHostBuilder().UseKestrel(GetKso()).UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).UseStartup().Build();
меняется на
var host = new WebHostBuilder().UseKestrel(GetKso()).UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).UseStartup().UseWebRoot("static").Build();

б) В список сервисов, которые добавляются в приложение, нужно добавить
app.UseStaticFiles();

в) Создать саму папку  static и положить туда хотя бы один файл

Результат: при запросе
`http://localhost:5000/index.html`
я получаю статическую страницу

**Шаг 3.**
Теперь нам осталось добавить REST.
Здесь пришлось сделать немного больше телодвижений, и я долго мучался, стараясь назначить кастомный роутинг на разные энпоинты. В конце концов я сдался, и оставил то, что называется роутингом по умолчанию.

Тогда суть сводится к добавлению в конфигурацию сервисов строки
services.AddControllers();

а в конфигурацию приложения двух дополнительных опций:

```
        app.UseRouting();
```

и

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
```

С самими контроллерами я не стал возиться, и просто скрестил свой пример с известным майкросфтовским примером WeatherForecast, ну и написал еще один очень примитивный контроллер MyController

Результат:
При обращения

`http://localhost:5000/WeatherForecast`
и
`http://localhost:5000/My`

у меня выводятся результаты работы метода Get контроллеров, а статическая страница тоже осталась на месте.

Все три шага лежат в [гитхабе](https://github.com/junecat/KestrelExample) в виде отдельных микропроектов.

Такой способ позволяет встроить простой рест - сервер в своё приложение и, например, добавить "красивую веб панель управления" к консольной утилите.

Спасибо за внимание и поддержку.