# Получить запрос с обработкой на .NET

Tags: c#

Возникла необходимость принятия и обработки POST запроса. Могу реализовать обработку на хостинге, записывая информацию в БД, и в приложении читать эту БД раз в минуту, но не считаю этот вариант достаточно.. элегантным.

Возможно каким либо образом через C# .NET создать URL, на который будут приходить запросы, и обрабатывать их внутри приложения?

Comment: я буквально несколько дней назад решал похожую задачу. встраивал примитивный веб - сервер в приложение. Мои результаты - в этом вопросе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1245445/

Comment: ASP.NET Core в помощь.