# Можно ли на IIS 7 запустить Web-application на Framework 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7

На сервере стоит Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise с IIS 7
Можно ли на веб-сервере IIS 7 запустить Web-application на Framework 4.5?

Пробовал пересобрать с помощью Framework 4.0, но не получается в проекте используются объекты ByteArrayContent и HttpResponseMessage, которых в Framework 4.0 нет.

```
public class FileApiController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/FileApi/UploadFile")]
        public void UploadFile()
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (var fileName in HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys)
                    {
                        HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[fileName];
                        if (file != null)
                        {
                            FileDTO fileDTO = new FileDTO();

                            fileDTO.FileActualName = file.FileName;
                            fileDTO.FileExt = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                            fileDTO.ContentType = file.ContentType;

                            DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
                            string fileUniqueNameExt = file.FileName.Replace(".", " " + dateTime.ToString().Replace('.', '_').Replace(':', '_') + ".");
                            fileDTO.FileUniqueName = fileUniqueNameExt.Substring(0, fileUniqueNameExt.LastIndexOf('.'));

                            var rootPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles");

                            var fileSavePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(rootPath, fileDTO.FileUniqueName + fileDTO.FileExt);

                            file.SaveAs(fileSavePath);

                            //Save File Meta data in Database
                            FileModel.SaveFileInDB(fileDTO);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<h3>" + ex.ToString() + "</h3>");
                }
            }
            var age = HttpContext.Current.Request["wayFile"];
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/FileApi/DownloadFile")]
        public Object DownloadFile(String uniqueName)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

            //Physical Path of Root Folder
            var rootPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles");

            //Find File from DB against unique name
            var fileDTO = FileModel.GetFileByUniqueID(uniqueName);

            if (fileDTO != null)
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                var fileFullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(rootPath, fileDTO.FileUniqueName + fileDTO.FileExt);

                byte[] file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileFullPath);
                System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(file);

                response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(file);
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
                //String mimeType = MimeType.GetMimeType(file); //You may do your hard coding here based on file extension

                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(fileDTO.ContentType);// obj.DocumentName.Substring(obj.DocumentName.LastIndexOf(".") + 1, 3);
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileDTO.FileActualName;
                return response;
            }
            else
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
                return response;
            }
        }
```

Какие возможны варианты решения данной проблемы?

Comment: Обновить сервер, работающий на устаревшей и небезопасной системе?

Comment: Это проблематично нужна же лицензия на Windows server 2012, а её нет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ - нет.

Можно сказать и вежливее - "к сожалению, нет".

В своё время я провел немало часов, пытаясь решить эту проблему. В сети есть несколько инструкций, которые вроде бы могут привести к успеху, но я попробовал их все - и в каждом случае столкнулся с какими либо проблемами, котроые не смог преодолеть.

Чисто теоретически, Вам может помочь переход на self-hosted веб-сервер: его можно запустить не только на устаревшей системе, но и вообще на любой современной винде или  линуксе.

я, когда встретился с необходимостью разрабатывать что то, работающее с помощью веб-сервера, стал использовать .NET и kestrel. У меня есть [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1245445/) работы с ним.

Вполне возможно, Вам будет проще адаптировать Ваше приложение к более "высокой" версии .NET, чем к более "низкой".

Если возникнут вопросы в процессе - можете написать в комментариях, подумаем вместе!

Дополнение, дополненное много времнеи спустя

Я тут увлекся "маленькими HTTP серверами" и понял, что можно жить вообще без IIS. Например, есть такая прелестная штука, которая называется [NancyFX](http://nancyfx.org/) ("lightweight, low-ceremony, framework for building HTTP based services on .NET Framework/Core and Mono", а https навешивать уже на уровне nginx'а), а еще в комментариях к моему [вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1261096/) aepot предложил еще более экономный вариант

Comment: Интересный опыт, было любопытно почитать!