# Современная альтернатива CGI приложений!

Tags: php, html, bash, cgi

Здравствуйте уважаемые коллеги!
В связи со служебной необходимостью ради интереса задался целью создать вэб приложение, которое через вэб форму восстанавливает бэкап базы 1с на удаленом сервере.
Не имея подобного рода опыта получилось вполне успешно через кучу костылей реализовать это средствами CGI.
Что имеется:

apache сервер

1с в docker контейнере

Вэб страница в формате .cgi
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как это работает - парсится конечная ссылка при отправлении, данные уходят в переменные и скрипт по ссш начинает работать с разными серверами.

Так вот сам вопрос. Скажите, есть ли какие-то современные средства для написания подобных программ?
Делал всё сам из открытой информации, всё получилось, хоть и не без труда, но хотелось бы научиться делать всё с интерактивными  оболочками, чувствую что уже не хватает функционала.
Скажите, на чем любителю можно попытаться написать аналогичные вэб приложения для решения рабочей рутины?
Хочу чтобы вэб страница запускала скрипты на удаленных серверах, делала это безопасно и интерактивно.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, то, что Вы ищеет - это "микро HTML сервер с обработкой REST запросов".

Эта архитектура чрезвычайно популярна.

Она позволяет делать следующее: у Вас появляется свой собственный сервер, на котором можно "хостить статику". А еще у него есть такое "местов коде", где обрабатываются REST запросы.

В результате у пользователя, зашедшего на этот "сервер", открывается в браузере SPA - single page application, одностарничное приложение.

Там - всё, как на большом сайте: CSS, красивая страничка, JS - фреймворки. А когда пользователь нажимает кнопку - команда улетает на тот сервер, который хостит приложение, и он может делать... да что угожно, Вы ведь сами пишете его код!

Дальнейшее зависит от платформы. Есть примеры на [C++](https://habr.com/ru/post/252519/) , [Python](https://habr.com/ru/post/276731/) - ну, а на C# их так много, что сами найдёте.

Другйо вопрос - как решить эту задачу, оставаясь в рамках PHP. Тут я, к сожалению, не ммогу ничего грамтно подсказать, потму что традиционно PHP хостится на "больших" WEB - серверах (Apache, nginx), и для них "правила игры" немножко другие.

Возможно, я не прав, тогда поправьте меня в комментариях, пожалуйста

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, прочитал всю статью. Думаю что понимаю принцип работы, но боюсь нужно будет потратить много времени, чтобы овладеть этим) Спасибо вам за помощь!

Comment: Дополню. В рамках php оставаться нет смысла, хочу переработать полностью само приложение. Пожалуй попробую сделать всё как описано в ссылке с примером на Python. C++ для меня темный лес, а на python'e думаю можно попробовать.

Comment: Посмотрите еще вот этот мой вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1245445/ А в статье про Python - да, там вроде всё довольно хорошо описано